# Javascript detect url with no hash

Tags: javascript, html, url, dom

Is there a way to detect the page's url change without using onhashchange? Because the url I'm trying to detect does not contain a hash. I tried add a listener on the window, like below, but it did not work. Many thanks!

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 window.addEventListener("onpageshow", myFunction); //this does not detect url change for me
    function myFunction() {   
    console.log("url  changed " );
    }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL changes when a new document is loaded, you can listen to the unload event of the current document to learn when that happens.

```
<body onunload="myFunction()">
```